# Clicked indicator for each item in v-for

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a nested v-for in which each items in the child v-for are clickable. I am trying to push into an array whichever item is clicked and its working well. However, I think its a bit dull if I don't have any indicator that these items were selected.

For example.
The `parent v-for` consists of week days(Monday to Sunday) while the `child v-for` consists of times(8AM,9AM, and so on...)

So I render it like so.

**HTML**

```
<div v-for"(day,d) in week_days">
    <p>{{day}}</p>
    <hr>
    <small>List of times</small>
    <p v-for="(time,t) in time_list"
        :class={'activeItem ': moment(day).format('MMMM DD YYYY')+' '+time == activeItem}
        @click="selectTime(<time and date object here>)"> {{time}} 
    </p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
selectTime(obj) {
    this.activeItem = obj.date+' '+obj.time; //2020-10-22 9:30PM
    this.selected_time.push(obj); //not related to the main problem
}
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

So far this one works, but only for a single item, not for all selected items.

The questions are:

1. How do I make it so that all the selected items are going to be indicated/marked as clicked.
2. As for the indicator/marker, instead of coloring the text into red, is it possible to replace whatever the item `{{time}}` into `Marked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a computed property with all the items that have been selected? Something like:

```
computed: {
  selectedItems() {
    return this.selected_item.map(item => item.format('LLL'))
  }
}
```

and then on your template you can check if the item is selected in your v-for loop:

```
<div v-for"(day,d) in week_days">
    <p>{{day}}</p>
    <hr>
    <small>List of times</small>
    <p v-for="(time,t) in time_list"
        :class={'activeItem ': selectedItems.includes(moment(day).format('LLL'))}
        @click="selectTime(<time and date object here>)"> {{time}} 
    </p>
</div>
```